# rails link_to body with action parameter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

I have an article table and a reply table.
Article with a column 'reply_count'. In view, I want to show replies count in my link_to, but I don't know how to do it.

here's controller code

```
class ArticleController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @article = Article.all
  end

end
```

here's article view

```
<%= link_to 'Reply(<%= article.replies_count %>)', path %>
```

I hope it can show like this

```
<a href=path> Reply(2) </a>
```

Need everybody's help, thanks...

Comment: I typed wrong word, reply_count should be replies_count, but it doesn't matter the question. Plz ignore it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String interpolation is the keyword. Please notice the double quotes, it will make `#{}` works

`<%= link_to "Reply #{article.replies_count}", path %>`